# $E[|X-\mu|^n] \le 2 E[|X-\mu|^{n+1}]$ for Integer Random Variables

Tags: probability

I would like to prove the following moment inequality for all integer random variables ($X\in\mathbb Z$) for which the $n+1$th moment is defined:
$$\mathrm{E}[|X-\mu|^n] \le 2 \mathrm E[|X-\mu|^{n+1}].$$
($n\ge1$, but probably doesn't have to be an integer.)
The constant, 2, can't be improved, since it is sharp for the Bernoulli distribution uniform over $\{0,1\}$.

We can assume $\mu=\mathrm E[X]\in[0,1/2]$ by shifting.
I know how to show that at least $\mathrm{E}[|X-\mu|^n] \le C \mathrm E[|X-\mu|^{n+1}]$ for *some* constant $C>0$, but I wonder how I might get the exact value 2.

Comment: Quick correction. The constant should be sharp for Bernoulli random variables with probability of 1 equal to 1/2. That is, for $X$ uniformly sampled from $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: @forgottenarrow Thanks! I have updated that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here is a proof: unfortunately, I had to do a distinction of cases...**

Let us assume wlog, as stated in the OP, that $\mu \in [0,1/2]$. First, observe that the desired inequality is equivalent to
$$
\mathbb{E}[ f_n(X-\mu) ] \geq 0, \qquad n \geq 1 \tag{1}
$$
where $f_n(x) = |x|^n(|x|-1/2)$. Now, by our assumption on $X$ (integer-valued) and $\mu\in[0,1/2]$, $f_n(X-\mu)$ is only negative for $X=0$.

- **Case 1:** Suppose $1-p_0 \leq \mu$. Then, we can rewrite
  $$\begin{align*}
  \mathbb{E}[ f_n(X-\mu) ] &= p_0\cdot f_n(\mu) + (1-p_0) \sum_{k\neq 0} \frac{p_k}{1-p_0} f_n(k-\mu)\\
  &= p_0\cdot f_n(\mu) + (1-p_0) \sum_{k\neq 0} \frac{p_k}{1-p_0} g_n(k-\mu)
  \end{align*}$$
  where we define $g_n(x)= |x|^n(|x|-1/2)_+\geq 0$ as the "corrected" version of $f_n$, such that $g_n$ is convex and
  $$
  g_n(x) = \begin{cases}
  0 & \text{ if } |x| \leq 1/2\\
  f_n(x) & \text{ otherwise.}
  \end{cases}
  $$
  By Jensen's inequality, we then have, letting $\nu := \sum_{k\neq 0} \frac{p_k}{1-p_0}\cdot k$,
  $$
  \mathbb{E}[ f_n(X-\mu) ] \geq  p_0\cdot f_n(\mu) + (1-p_0) \cdot g_n(\nu -\mu)
  \geq  p_0 f_n(\mu) + (1-p_0)  f_n(\nu -\mu) \tag{2}
  $$
  the second inequality since $g_n\geq f_n$ by construction. Note that $(1-p_0)\nu = \mu$; thus, we just showed that the extremal case is for the two-point setting, i.e., letting $Y\sim\mathrm{Bern}(1-p_0)$
  $$
  \mathbb{E}[ f_n(X-\mu) ] \geq  \mathbb{E}[ f_n(\nu Y-\mu) ] \tag{3}
  $$
  for which is is relatively easy to check that the inequality holds, using that from our assumption we have $\nu \geq 1$. *(The idea here is that this is necessary, as for $\nu < 1$ we would drop in in our reduction the initial assumption that $X$ cannot take values in $(0,1)$, which is crucial.)* To see why, recalling that $\nu-\mu = \frac{\mu p_0}{1-p_0} \geq p_0 \geq 1-\mu \geq \frac12$,
  $$
  \begin{align}
  \mathbb{E}[ f_n(\nu Y-\mu) ]
  &= p_0 \mu^n\left(\mu-\frac12\right) + (1-p_0) \mu^n\left( \frac{p_0}{1-p_0} \right)^n\left(\frac{\mu p_0}{1-p_0}-\frac12\right) \\
  &\geq p_0 \mu^n\left(\mu-\frac12\right) + (1-p_0) \mu^n\left( \frac{p_0}{1-p_0} \right)^n\left(\frac12 - \mu\right) \\
  &= \mu^n p_0 \left(\frac12 - \mu\right) \left(   \left( \frac{p_0}{1-p_0} \right)^{n-1} - 1\right) \geq 0
  \end{align}
  $$
  the last inequality recalling that $p_0\geq 1/2$ from our assumption.
- **Case 2:** Suppose $1-p_0 > \mu$. Then, since $f_n$ is even, and increasing on $[1/2, \infty)$, $f_n(k-\mu) \geq f_n(1-\mu)$ for all $k\neq 0$, so that we have
  $$\begin{align*}
  \mathbb{E}[ f_n(X-\mu) ] &= p_0\cdot f_n(\mu) + \sum_{k\neq 0} p_k\cdot  f_n(k-\mu)\\
  &\geq p_0\cdot f_n(\mu) + (1-p_0) \cdot f_n(1-\mu) \\
  &= p_0 \mu^n (\mu-\tfrac12) + (1-p_0) (1-\mu)^n (\tfrac12-\mu) \\
  &= (\tfrac12-\mu)( (1-p_0) (1-\mu)^n - p_0\mu^n  )\\
  &\geq (\tfrac12-\mu)\mu (1-\mu)( (1-\mu)^{n-1} - \mu^{n-1}  ) \tag{as $1-p_0 > \mu$}\\
  &\geq 0
  \end{align*}$$
  the last inequality since $\mu \leq 1/2$.         $\;\;\square$

Comment: This is neat! What are the values that $Y$ takes? I couldn't deduce it from the last 2 equations here.

Comment: @rookie You're right, i said Bernoulli, but it's a two-point setting. Fixing that

Comment: RHS of (2) evaluated at $p_0 = 1/2$ is $\mu^n(\mu - 1)$, which is negative. Is the inequality loose?

Comment: @rookie the issue here is that we could have $\nu < 1$, which should not happen in the original version of the problem (integer-valued). The argument works for $\nu \geq 1$ I think...

Comment: @rookie It's fixed.  I had to do a distinction of cases, though...

Comment: I think using similar ideas you can also get $2 E |X-\mu|^{n+1}- E |X-\mu|^n \ge -\frac{1}{(1+1/n)^n}\cdot\frac{1}{(n+1)2^n}$ for $X$ real. (As above, bound by convex $g$ and then Jensen, but use a *lower* bound $g\le f$.)

Answer (score 5):

**Proof by induction for integer $n\geq 1.$**
Without loss of generality, assume $\mu \in [0, 1)$.

**Proof for $n=1$. (basis for induction)**
First notice that
\begin{align}
0 = E[X-\mu] &= - \sum_{i = 0}^\infty  p_{-i} (\mu + i) + \sum_{j=1}^\infty p_j (j- \mu)
\end{align}
Thus,
\begin{align}
E[|X-\mu|] &= \sum_{i = 0}^\infty  p_{-i} (\mu + i) + \sum_{j=1}^\infty p_j (j- \mu)\\
& = 2\sum_{i = 0}^\infty  p_{-i} (\mu + i) = 2\sum_{j=1}^\infty p_j (j- \mu).
\end{align}
We have
\begin{align}
E[|X - \mu|^2] &= \sum_{i = 0}^\infty  p_{-i} (\mu + i)^{2} + \sum_{j=1}^\infty  p_j (j-\mu)^{2} \\
& \geq \mu \sum_{i = 0}^\infty  p_{-i} (\mu + i) + (1-\mu) \sum_{j=1}^\infty  p_j (j-\mu)\\
& = \frac{\mu}{2} E[|X-\mu|] + \frac{1-\mu}{2} E[|X-\mu|]\\
& = \frac{1}{2} E[|X-\mu|],
\end{align}
which completes the proof for $n=1$. The inequality is achieved with equality if and only if $X \sim \mathcal{B}(q)$ for some $q \in [0,1)$.

**Proof for integer $n\geq 1$.** (proof due to @user8675309 in the comments).
The proof proceeds by induction. The base case for $n=1$ is already provided.

*Induction hypothesis.* Assume that the inequality holds for some integer $n$.

Then,
\begin{equation}
E[|X - \mu|^{n+1}]^2 \leq  E[|X - \mu|^{n}] E[|X - \mu|^{n+2}] \leq 2E[|X - \mu|^{n+1}] E[|X - \mu|^{n+2}],
\end{equation}
completing the proof. The first inequality is due to Cauchy-Schwarz, and the second inequality follows from the induction hypothesis. The first inequality is tight if and only if $|X-\mu|$ is a constant, and the second inequality is achieved if and only if $X \sim \mathcal{B}(q)$ for some $q \in [0,1)$. Putting the two together, for $n>1$, the inequality is strict unless $X \sim \mathcal{B}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ or $X \sim \mathcal{B}\left( 0 \right)$ (i.e., $X=0$). For $n=1$, inequality is strict unless $X \sim \mathcal{B}(q)$ for some $q \in [0,1)$.

Comment: That's very nice!

Comment: Very nice! Note that viewed as a base case, this immediately gives the proof for all $n$. Define $Y:= \vert X-\mu\vert$.  By induction we know this relationship holds for $Y^{n}$ relative to $Y^{n+1}$ and prove that it holds for $Y^{n+1}$ relative to $Y^{n+2}$ because $\mathbb E[Y^{n+1}]^2\leq \mathbb E[Y^{n}]\cdot \mathbb E[Y^{n+2}]\leq \big(2\cdot\mathbb E[Y^{n+1}]\big)\cdot\mathbb E[Y^{n+2}] \implies \mathbb E[Y^{n+1}]\leq 2 \cdot \mathbb E[Y^{n+2}] $  where the first inequality is Cauchy-Schwarz and the second is the induction hypothesis.

Comment: to expand on use of Cauchy-Schwarz:  
$Y\geq 0$ so it admits a square root, now e.g. consider the determinant of the following Gram Matrix $G = \begin{bmatrix}
\mathbb E[Z_1 Z_1] &\mathbb E[Z_1 Z_2] \\
 \mathbb E[Z_2 Z_1] & \mathbb E[Z_2 Z_2]\\
\end{bmatrix}$
with $Z_1:= Y^\frac{n}{2}$  and $Z_2:= Y^\frac{n+2}{2}$ .  Taking the determinant recovers Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: @user8675309 
Neat! Yes, that immediately extend the proof for all integer $n\geq 1$.

Comment: @user8675309 I updated the proof with your neat extension by induction. Hope that is fine.